# Using SSLv3 in IIS 6.0

Tags: security, iis, ssl

I recently got a notification from a McAfee service (what used to be called HackerSafe) that my website is using SSLv2 and it should be using SSLv3. I don't know anything about the versions of SSL. My site is using IIS 6.0, is there a setting somewhere to turn on SSLv3 or do I need to install something to make this happen? Also, is there any drawbacks to only using SSLv3? Are there browsers that can only use v2?

Comment: I know ServerFault didn't exist at the time this was asked, but I think it belongs there now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has a KB article on disabling SSLv3, obviously it's in the same place as enabling it.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187498/en-us

Answer (score 10):

The [Microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187498/en-us) referenced in TravisO's answer is helpful for general reference.  I used the information from that article along with information gathered from ServerSniff.net's [SSL analysis tool](http://serversniff.net/sslcheck.php)

Also, you can copy and paste the following snippet into a .reg file to quickly disable SSLv2 on a web farm:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

In regards to browser support for SSLv3, the following information should help (taken from the McAfee Scan Alert):

> In Internet Explorer 7, the default
>   HTTPS protocol settings are changed to
>   disable the weaker SSLv2 protocol and
>   to enable the stronger TLSv1 protocol.
>   By default, IE7 users will only
>   negotiate HTTPS connections using
>   SSLv3 or TLSv1. Mozilla Firefox is
>   expected to drop support for SSLv2 in
>   its upcoming versions.
>
> As almost all modern browsers support
>   SSLv3, disabling support for the
>   weaker SSL method should have minimal
>   impact. The following browsers support
>   SSLv3:
>
> - Internet Explorer 5.5 or higher (PC)
> - Internet Explorer 5.0 or higher (Mac)
> - Netscape 2.0 (Domestic) or higher (PC/Mac)
> - Firefox 0.8 or higher (PC/Mac/Linux)
> - Mozilla 1.7 or higher (PC/Mac/Linux)
> - Camino 0.8 or higher (Mac)
> - Safari 1.0 or higher (Mac)
> - Opera 1.7 or higher (PC/Mac)
> - Omniweb 3.0 or higher (Mac)
> - Konqueror 2.0 or higher (Linux)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at fixing this you will probably also want the to fix weak ciphers since most scanners will complain about both. That is [Microsoft KB245030](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030). Generally any browser that supports SSLv3 will also support newer and stronger ciphers than the ones turned off by the scripts at that link.